# More than one condition in Rendered in VF page

Tags: visualforce

I have the code like below. I need to add user's country checking code also with the Rendered section in below. Like if country code is = IN then and account is null or blank then only the code will work. Pls suggest.

```
  <apex:page standardController="Event_Cost_c" rendered="{!ISBLANK(Event_Cost__c.Account__c)}">
```

Comment: Why don't you call a method like `rendered="{!myMethod}` that do all the job you want?

Answer (score 3):

Check my similar answer on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20671252/visualforce-if-statement-need-to-know-syntax-for-or

In your case something like this probably would work:

```
rendered="{!Event_Cost__c.Country_Code__c = 'IN' && ISBLANK(Event_Cost__c.Account__c)}"
```

It's not too different from the syntax of normal formulas.